# Adding a seperator to the tableview causes a layoutconstraint error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have an issue of showing a simple cell in a UITableViewController.
My cell contains of just an UIImage. The image has a top-, leading and a bottom space of 20. The height and the width of the image are 60.

I kept receiving the following NSLayoutConstraint issue.

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001d6e030 UIImageView:0x7f8a37c218c0.height == 60   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001d6d9a0 V:|-(20)-[UIImageView:0x7f8a37c218c0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a37c1bb70 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001d6c280 V:[UIImageView:0x7f8a37c218c0]-(20)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a37c1bb70 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001d6f430 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8a37c1bb70.height == 100.333   (active)>"
```

I did not add the last one myself. It probably autogenerates the height of the whole view.

After a  while I found out that deleting the seperator of the tableview ensured that there was no conflict anymore

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
```

I don't want to use a custom UIView as a seperator, how can I fix this. The app is breaking the height constraint of the image, which actually is not a big deal. Because the image will now be 60.333, but I want to know what is going wrong.

I have already tried adding automaticDimention and an estimatedRowHeight without succes

Setting the separatorStyle to none, will fix the error. But there should be a smarter solution for this.

Comment: can you added height for cell using heightForRowAt method ??

Comment: Give your Height constraint a Priority of 999

Comment: Setting priority is indeed removing the errors, I think I will use that solution for now.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

> The image has a top-, leading and a bottom space of 20. The height and the width of the image are 20.

That is the issue. No need to set top and bottom alongside height

This may be solved by using

- Keep the height width fixed
- Remove the top and bottom
- Make CenterY of ImageView and CenterY of Cell equal

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60 // top 20 + imageView 20 + bottom 20 
    }
```

Or

- keep top and bottom constraint and remove height, keep the width only

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return 60 // top 20 + imageView 20 + bottom 20 
}
```

Comment: I assume it also has to work without setting the heightForRow method. My problem is that it works perfectly without this method when there is no seperator. But adding the seperator, I receive an error.